# Open emoji keyboard layout on editText click

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyboard, emoji

I want to let the user only type emojis in an editText field. Is there a way to instantly show the emoji keyboard of the android keyboard when you click on a editText field?

Right now I helped myself with the `android:inputType="textShortMessage"` The problem here is, I always have to push the emoji icon in the bottom corner to open the emoji keyboard.

Does anybody have a clue? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: "Is there a way to instantly show the emoji keyboard of the android keyboard when you click on a editText field?" -- not every user of your app will have an "emoji keyboard".